# Are there standards for Graphql schema specifications?

Tags: graphql

I've been exploring Graphql for a project and I'm fairly new to it. I came across Relay JS by Facebook. It has a [specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html) on how schema should be defined. My concern with this specification is it's somewhat tied to a JS framework.

Are there other specifications for defining Graphql schema?

Comment: were the answers helpful @wagaboy?

Comment: @nburk Appreciate your time in answering my questions. I'm still new, so it may take a few more days to understand and evaluate the APIs you listed. I'll get back to this thread :)

Comment: awesome! let me know if you have any further questions and don't forget to tick the green checkmark on one of the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no standards for creating GraphQL schemas!

Relay is the only GraphQL client right now that is *opinionated* about what your GraphQL Schema should look like, but I still wouldn't call it a *standard*. With all other clients (like Apollo or Lokka) the schema can be designed in any way you like!

For inspiration, you might want to take a look at how we design the GraphQL API at [Graphcool](https://www.graph.cool). We're providing two different APIs:

- [Relay API](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/relay-api/overview-aizoong9ah/): Follows the requirements of Relay
- [Simple API](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/overview-heshoov3ai/): Basic CRUD capabilities for each type in your data model

You can additionally include capabilities like ordering or filtering in the API.

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on the server. If you dont need relay (like in my case) i have a custom scheme mapping to mysql db.

You are free to define your own scheme as long as each field is a graphql field